# Using attributes of `ftable` for extracting data

Tags: r, subset

I sometimes use the `ftable` function purely for its presentation of hierarchical categories. However, sometimes, when the table is large, I would like to further subset the table before using it.

Let's say we're starting with:

```
mytable <- ftable(Titanic, row.vars = 1:3)
mytable
##                    Survived  No Yes
## Class Sex    Age                   
## 1st   Male   Child            0   5
##              Adult          118  57
##       Female Child            0   1
##              Adult            4 140
## 2nd   Male   Child            0  11
##              Adult          154  14
##       Female Child            0  13
##              Adult           13  80
## 3rd   Male   Child           35  13
##              Adult          387  75
##       Female Child           17  14
##              Adult           89  76
## Crew  Male   Child            0   0
##              Adult          670 192
##       Female Child            0   0
##              Adult            3  20

str(mytable)
##  ftable [1:16, 1:2] 0 118 0 4 0 154 0 13 35 387 ...
##  - attr(*, "row.vars")=List of 3
##   ..$ Class: chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
##   ..$ Sex  : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
##   ..$ Age  : chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
##  - attr(*, "col.vars")=List of 1
##   ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
## NULL
```

Because there are no `dimnames`, I can't extract data in the same way that I would with an object that has `dimnames`. For instance, there's no way for me to directly extract all the "Child" values from the "1st" and "3rd" classes.

My current approach is to convert it to a `table`, do the extraction, and then convert it back to an `ftable`.

Example:

```
mytable[c("1st", "3rd"), , "Child", ]
## Error: incorrect number of dimensions

## Only the underlying data are seen as having dims
dim(mytable)
## [1] 16  2

## I'm OK with the "Age" column being dropped in this case....
ftable(as.table(mytable)[c("1st", "3rd"), , "Child", ])
##              Survived No Yes
## Class Sex                   
## 1st   Male             0   5
##       Female           0   1
## 3rd   Male            35  13
##       Female          17  14
```

However, I don't like this approach because the overall layout sometimes changes if you're not careful. Compare it with the following, which removes the requirement of subsetting only children and adds the requirement of subsetting only those who did not survive:

```
ftable(as.table(mytable)[c("1st", "3rd"), , , "No"])
##              Age Child Adult
## Class Sex                   
## 1st   Male           0   118
##       Female         0     4
## 3rd   Male          35   387
##       Female        17    89
```

I don't like that the overall layout of rows and columns has changed. That's a classic case of having to remember to use `drop = FALSE` to maintain dimensions when a single column is extracted:

```
ftable(as.table(mytable)[c("1st", "3rd"), , , "No", drop = FALSE])
##                    Survived  No
## Class Sex    Age               
## 1st   Male   Child            0
##              Adult          118
##       Female Child            0
##              Adult            4
## 3rd   Male   Child           35
##              Adult          387
##       Female Child           17
##              Adult           89
```

I know there are *many* ways to get the data that I want, starting with subsetting from the raw data and then making my `ftable`, but for this question, let's assume that's not possible.

The end goal is to have an approach that lets me extract from an `ftable` preserving the display format of the nested "row" hierarchy.

Are there other solutions to this? Can we make use of the `row.vars` and `col.vars` attributes to extract data from an `ftable` and retain its formatting?

---

My current approach also doesn't work for hierarchical columns, so I'm hoping that the proposed solution can also handle those cases.

Example:

```
tab2 <- ftable(Titanic, row.vars = 1:2, col.vars = 3:4)
tab2
##              Age      Child     Adult    
##              Survived    No Yes    No Yes
## Class Sex                                
## 1st   Male                0   5   118  57
##       Female              0   1     4 140
## 2nd   Male                0  11   154  14
##       Female              0  13    13  80
## 3rd   Male               35  13   387  75
##       Female             17  14    89  76
## Crew  Male                0   0   670 192
##       Female              0   0     3  20
```

Note the nesting of "Age" and "Survived".

Try my current approach:

```
ftable(as.table(tab2)[c("1st", "3rd"), , , , drop = FALSE])
##                    Survived  No Yes
## Class Sex    Age                   
## 1st   Male   Child            0   5
##              Adult          118  57
##       Female Child            0   1
##              Adult            4 140
## 3rd   Male   Child           35  13
##              Adult          387  75
##       Female Child           17  14
##              Adult           89  76
```

I can get back to what I want with:

```
ftable(as.table(tab2)[c("1st", "3rd"), , , , drop = FALSE], row.vars = 1:2, col.vars = 3:4)
```

But I'm hoping for something more direct.

Comment: I've gone down this road before. Gave up and now I subset the raw data and use `ftable` on that.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, did you make any progress that you'd like to share? I like `ftable`, but it's sad that it seems to be so neglected. It doesn't even have a proper `as.data.frame` method....

Comment: Is your desired outcome to review the output in the console or are you intending to format this table for use in a document? Are you open to an alternative approach that doesn't use `ftable`?

Comment: @KevinArseneau, more for review at the console, and out of curiosity what the best way to do this would be. I know there are several packages that create great LaTeX and HTML tables for reports that have hierarchical rows and columns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's what I was able to sort of hack together, with [some help](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40590105#40590105) from [Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4341440/axeman):

```
replace_empty_arguments <- function(a) {
  empty_symbols <- vapply(a, function(x) {
    is.symbol(x) && identical("", as.character(x)), 0)
  } 
  a[!!empty_symbols] <- 0
  lapply(a, eval)
}

`[.ftable` <- function (inftable, ...) {
  if (!class(inftable) %in% "ftable") stop("input is not an ftable")
  tblatr <- attributes(inftable)[c("row.vars", "col.vars")]
  valslist <- replace_empty_arguments(as.list(match.call()[-(1:2)]))
  x <- sapply(valslist, function(x) identical(x, 0))
  TAB <- as.table(inftable)
  valslist[x] <- dimnames(TAB)[x]
  temp <- as.matrix(expand.grid(valslist))
  out <- ftable(
    `dimnames<-`(`dim<-`(TAB[temp], lengths(valslist)), valslist),
    row.vars = seq_along(tblatr[["row.vars"]]),
    col.vars = seq_along(tblatr[["col.vars"]]) + length(tblatr[["row.vars"]]))
  names(attributes(out)[["row.vars"]]) <- names(tblatr[["row.vars"]])
  names(attributes(out)[["col.vars"]]) <- names(tblatr[["col.vars"]])
  out
}
```

Try it out with the examples from the question:

```
mytable[c("1st", "3rd"), , "Child", ]
##                    Survived No Yes
## Class Sex    Age                  
## 1st   Male   Child           0   5
##       Female Child           0   1
## 3rd   Male   Child          35  13
##       Female Child          17  14

mytable[c("1st", "3rd"), , , "No"]
##                    Survived  No
## Class Sex    Age               
## 1st   Male   Child            0
##              Adult          118
##       Female Child            0
##              Adult            4
## 3rd   Male   Child           35
##              Adult          387
##       Female Child           17
##              Adult           89

tab2[c("1st", "3rd"), , , ]
##              Age      Child     Adult    
##              Survived    No Yes    No Yes
## Class Sex                                
## 1st   Male                0   5   118  57
##       Female              0   1     4 140
## 3rd   Male               35  13   387  75
##       Female             17  14    89  76
```

Answer (score 4):

Once the data is aggregated to frequencies by combination of factors as is the case with the `Titanic` data set, it is arguably easier to subset the raw data and tabulate it for display rather than manipulating the output object.

I recognize that the OP asks for solutions using `ftable`, but with the back and forth in the comments section soliciting other ideas, I thought I'd post a different take on this question because it illustrates a way to simultaneously subset the data and generate the hierarchical structure of the contingency tables without custom functions.

Here is an approach using the `tables` package that preserves the hierarchical structure of the `Titanic` data, as well as eliminating cells that are empty when we subset the data frame.

First we cast the incoming table as a data frame so we can subset it during the `tabular()` function.

```
 library(titanic)
 df <- as.data.frame(Titanic)
```

Then we use `tables::tabular()` while subsetting the data in the `data=` argument with the extract operator `[`, and use `DropEmpty()` to avoid printing rows and columns where `Freq == 0`. We also use `Heading()` to suppress unwanted headings for `Freq` and `sum`.

```
tabular((Class * Sex) ~ (Age)*Survived*Heading()*Freq*Heading()*sum*DropEmpty(empty=0),
        data=df[df$Class %in% c("1st","3rd") & df$Age=="Child",])
```

...and the output:

```
> tabular((Class * Sex) ~ (Age)*Survived*Heading()*Freq*Heading()*sum*DropEmpty(empty=0),
+         data=df[df$Class %in% c("1st","3rd") & df$Age=="Child",])

              Age         
              Child       
              Survived    
 Class Sex    No       Yes
 1st   Male    0        5 
       Female  0        1 
 3rd   Male   35       13 
       Female 17       14
```

If we remove `DropEmpty()`, we replicate the entire tabular structure based on the factor variables in the table.

```
> # remove DropEmpty() to replicate entire factor structure
> tabular((Class * Sex) ~ (Age)*Survived*Heading()*Freq*Heading()*sum,
+         data=df[df$Class %in% c("1st","3rd") & df$Age=="Child",])

              Age                      
              Child        Adult       
              Survived     Survived    
 Class Sex    No       Yes No       Yes
 1st   Male    0        5  0        0  
       Female  0        1  0        0  
 2nd   Male    0        0  0        0  
       Female  0        0  0        0  
 3rd   Male   35       13  0        0  
       Female 17       14  0        0  
 Crew  Male    0        0  0        0  
       Female  0        0  0        0  
>
```

Replicating the second and third examples from the OP is also straightforward.

```
> # second example from question
> tabular((Class * Sex * Age) ~ Survived*Heading()*Freq*Heading()*sum*DropEmpty(empty=0),
+         data=df[df$Class %in% c("1st","3rd") & df$Survived=="No",])

                    Survived
 Class Sex    Age   No      
 1st   Male   Child   0     
              Adult 118     
       Female Child   0     
              Adult   4     
 3rd   Male   Child  35     
              Adult 387     
       Female Child  17     
              Adult  89     
> # third example from question 
> tabular((Class * Sex) ~ (Age)*Survived*Heading()*Freq*Heading()*sum*DropEmpty(empty=0),
+         data=df[df$Class %in% c("1st","3rd"),])

              Age                      
              Child        Adult       
              Survived     Survived    
 Class Sex    No       Yes No       Yes
 1st   Male    0        5  118       57
       Female  0        1    4      140
 3rd   Male   35       13  387       75
       Female 17       14   89       76
>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the "tables" package, which I use in reports, but as mentioned in my comments under the question, that's not exactly what I was after. Still, some good examples here of the features of `tabular` for those who might not be familiar with it.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 - Understood that the original question was about `ftable()`, as I noted in my response. I think it's easier to aggregate to a narrow format tidy data set, and subset the data in the `data=` argument of `tabular()` to display it hierarchically than it is to manipulate the object structure output by `ftable()`.  That said, the `ftable()` specific version of the extract operator that you posted is a creative way to manipulate `ftable()` objects.