# Count number of rows based on 3 unique conditions with many (over 50) possible combinations

Tags: r, vectorization, apply

I have some data where each row represents one flower. I'm trying to count the number of rows in the dataframe based on 3 variables. Here is a sample of what the data looks like.

```
 ï..petal_size stem_length flow_color
1         large         long      red  
2         small        short     orange
3         large        short     yellow
4          small        long       blue
5         large       short       green
6          small       long     indigo 
7         large        short     violet
8          small        long      red  
9         large       short      orange
10         small      short      yellow
11        large         long       blue
12         small        long      green
13        large         long    indigo 
14         small       short     violet
15        large         long      red  
16        large         long     orange
17        large         long     yellow
18         small      short        blue
19         small        long      green
20         small       short    indigo 
21        large         long     violet
```

The hard part is that I want code that will sum up the number of rows for each possible combination and there are many possible combinations. The possible combinations are based on values in 3 different columns, which are flower color (7 values), petal_length (2 values), and stem_length (2 values). I then would like to make a count of these values either by adding it to a matrix that looks like this

[image]

I could probably write some sort of triple for loop for each variable or a series of long if statements with multiple conditions, but that sounds like it will require a lot of lines of code and be computationally inefficient. The full final dataset will be very large so this isn't a viable solution. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe `as.data.frame(table(dat))` if your data.frame is named dat.

Comment: Yes thank you that counts all the possible combinations, but I'm trying to organize the counts into a matrix so I can also perform perform sums on rows and columns. I'll clarify this in the question

Comment: The `table` function returns a value that has dimensions, so it can be used as an array. In R matrices have only 2 dimensions and your problem has 3. (There are many asked and answered questions like this one where `table` seems the obvious answer. You should do some searching on SO.) You may want the facilities of `ftable`, given your picture in the edit, but again there are many asked and answered questions that involve `ftable`.

Comment: @42- the matrix (or dataframe) I'm looking for would only use 2 dimensions, which you can see above

Comment: Yes, I can read. You are displaying the third dimension (large versus small) by putting them side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in a dataframe, then the `ftable` function provides exactly what is needed:

```
ftable(dat, row.vars="flow_color")
#-------
           petal_size  large       small      
           stem_length  long short  long short
flow_color                                    
blue                       1     0     1     1
green                      0     1     2     0
indigo                     1     0     1     1
orange                     1     1     0     1
red                        2     0     1     0
violet                     1     1     0     1
yellow                     1     1     0     1
```

Here's another possible avenue. The "best" answer involved the tabular package: [Using attributes of `ftable` for extracting data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47974442/using-attributes-of-ftable-for-extracting-data)

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I want! However, I get a slightly different output for some reason. For some reason I get small twice and also I get this for stem length `long long  short short   long long  short short    long long  short short`

Comment: You probably have different spellings of your levels. Spaces at the beginning or end will confuse things. Look at the result so length(unique(...) ) for your columns. You _should_ have presented the results of `dput(data_object, 20))`